# Multiple SELECTs vs Single Query with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

Our current setup looks a bit like this.

public_entry (5.000.000 rows) → telephone_number (5.000.000 rows) → user (400.000 rows)

3 tables, the arrow to the right indicating a foreign key constraint containing a foreign key (integer) from the right table.

Now we have two "views" of the data we want to present in our web app.

1. displaying telephone numbers with public entries based on user attributes (e.g. only numbers from male users), a bit like a score.
2. displaying telephone numers with public entries based on their entry date

Each result should get a score assigned whether the number fits your needs (e.g. you look for a plumber, if the number is in you area an the related user is a plumber the telephone number should score high).

We tried several approaches on solving this problem with two scenarios.

The first approach does a SELECT with INNER JOINs over the table, like the following

```
SELECT ..., (...) as score
    FROM public_entry pe
    INNER JOIN telephone_numer tn ON tn.id = pe.numberid
    INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = tn.userid WHERE ... ORDER BY score
```

using this query on smaller system, 1/4 of the production system performs very very well, even under load.
However when we put this query in the production system it wrecked havoc with execution times over 30 seconds.

The second approach was getting all public_entries filtered with a single SELECT on public_entry without any JOINs and iterating over them an calling a SELECT for each public_entry fetching the telephone_number and user, computing the score and discarding the results if telephone_number and user do not match our filter/interest.

Usually the second approach is never considered, because it creates over 300 queries for a single page load. Foreach'ing over results and calling SELECTs within a foreach is usually considered bad style.

However approach number two performs on the production system. Not well but does not tak more tahn 1-3 seconds, but also performs bad on the test systems.

Do you have any suggestions on where the problem might be?

**EDIT:**

Query

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id)
    FROM public_entry p, fon f, user u
    WHERE p.isweb = 1
      AND f.hidden = 0
      AND f.deleted = 0
      AND f.id = p.fonid
      AND u.id = f.userid
      AND u.gender = "female"
```

This query has 3 seconds execution time.

[image]

This is just an example query. I can take out the where and it performs just a bit worse. In general if we do a SELECT COUNT() with a single INNER JOIN over the data the query blows up (30 seconds)

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual queries you are running along with explains, table schema information, desired query results, etc. I am doubtful that nested queries is a good solution.

Comment: @MikeBrant I ll try to add some more information

Comment: Some really useful information would be the explain plan for the query. Describe the query by prepending `DESC` to it, e.g. `DESC SELECT ...`. The likely culprit is a lack of covering indexes for your query. With that explain plan, we can suggest indexes that may help.

Comment: Performance depends heavily on (1) the WHERE clause, and (2) the INDEXes.  Please show us both.  In your particular case, the ORDER BY cannot be used for optimizing.

Comment: @RickJames I ll be adding the information in the next hours.

Comment: @RickJames MikeBrant I added the information requested. I can provide more detail if needed

Comment: Is `public_entry` to `telephone_number` 1:1?  If so, can't they be in a single table?  If not, is it "close" to 1:1, such that a single table could have all the columns of both, perhaps with a few duplicates and/or NULLs?  I bring this up because the main inefficiency in the query is that the WHERE clause is spread across 3 tables.

Comment: @RickJames they basically are and they will be merged in the future. This is just the result of some legacy design.

Comment: Until they are merged, there is not a lot that can be done to speed up the SELECT.  (And I am not sure what can be done even then.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the magic answer you want, but here are some 'reasons' for poor performance, and some *possible* workarounds (with caveats).

Which of `isweb`, `hidden`, `deleted`, and `gender` are the most 'selective'?  This optimizer sees them as useless and annoying.  That is, if each has two values and an INDEX on that field is probably useless.  Hence, it picks one table, does a full scan, then reaches into the next table, etc.  Notice, in the `EXPLAIN` that it picked the smallest table (`user`) first.  This is typically what the optimizer does when none of the `WHERE` clause looks useful.

Whether MySQL does all that work, or you do all that work is about the same amount of effort.  Perhaps you can do it faster since you can have a simple associative arrays in memory, while MySQL is coded to allow for the tables to live on disk an be "cached" in RAM, block by block.  But, if you don't have enough RAM to load everything in, you are stuck with MySQL.

If you actually removed "hidden" and "deleted" rows, the task would be a little faster.

Your two SELECTs do not look much alike.  Are you suggesting there is a wide range of SELECTs?  And you effectively need to look through most of all 3 tables to get the "score" or "count"?

Let's look at this from a Data Warehouse approach...  Is some of the data "static"; that is, unchanging and could be summarized?  If so, precomputing subtotals (`COUNT(*)`) into a summary table would let the ultimate queries be a lot faster.  DW often involves subtotals by day.  But it requires that these subtotals don't change.

`COUNT(x)` has the overhead of checking `x` for being `NULL`.  Usually that is not necessary and `COUNT(*)` gives you what you want.

How often are you running the same SELECT?  Or, at least, similar SELECTs?  Do you need up-to-the-second scores?  I'm fishing for running all the likely queries in the middle of the night, then using the results for 24 hours.  Note that some queries can run faster by doing multiple things at once.  For example, instead of two SELECTs for 'female' versus 'male', do one SELECT and `GROUP BY gender`.

Comment: Most of the results change on an hourly bases, when users add new entries. Usually there is a 4th JOIN on a location table, displaying only results for a given area, so we could try and cache the results per area. The problem is then, we'd have to compute the score afterwards. This cache'ing technique would not work for the sorted by score view, since each of these views is individual to the users need and has too many invariants, we would basically end up caching too many different result sets only to be fast for 1 specific user.